# Disabled date later than today's date in datepicker windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm using the DatePicker from the windows phone 8 toolkit, and I want to disable the dates later than today's. 
How can I do that in my custom DatePicker?

Comment: Telerik offers a DatePicker control that has these capabilities (but not for free):
http://www.telerik.com/windows-universal-ui

You also won't be able to do that without recreating the datepicker from scratch.

Comment: I tried to implement it by myself, but I got stuck.
If someone could share a code that does it, I'll be more than grateful.

Comment: You mean the phone toolkit from phone.codeplex.com, right? Then you should start in the DateTimePicker/DataSource.cs and modify the day/month/year datasource classes to check if the date is below your Maximum date, before returning the value. It's super tricky and you will have to check diverse updates in the control. Did that once, I'll check for the code tomorrow.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I meant(I used the DatePicker and not the DateTimePicker, but DateTimePicker will be great too). it's super tricky - this is why I got stuck :)
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I updated the answer with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible with the default DatePicker. You can only limit the minimum and maximum year.

Updated as by comments above:

When using the phone toolkit timepicker, you can change the behavior in the *DateSource classes of the toolkit.
Here is an example where I added a maximum day.
Returning null from GetRelativeTo(...) breaks the looping selector and it stops at the end.

```
    internal class DayDataSource : DataSource
    {
        protected override DateTime? GetRelativeTo(DateTime relativeDate, int delta)
        {
            var nextDay = relativeDate.AddDays(delta);
            if (nextDay.Date < DateTime.Now.Date || nextDay.Date > MaxValue.Date)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new DateTime(relativeDate.Year, relativeDate.Month, nextDay.Day, relativeDate.Hour, relativeDate.Minute, 0);
        }
    }
```

You will have to figure out some more details for the implementation and I remember it took me some time to get through it.